# css - left sidebar not on left side

Tags: html, css, sidebar, navigationbar

The left sidebar won't position itself on the left side of the main area. It seems to get stuck on the navigation link. It should be placed "below" the navigation links and the "buttons" should overlap the sidebar just as they overlap the header. Then I want the text to wrap around the sidebar (works in the code I posted here).

I have tried using `z-index` on the navigation and sidebar. I have also tried using `position:relative;` and `float:left;` on the sidebar without result. The text should also wrap around the sidebar as it is in the example below. I managed to move the sidebar to the left using `position:relative;` but then the text won't wrap it.

**HTML:**

```
<html lang="sv">
<head>
<link href="layout1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="topbanner">
    <h1>TopBanner</h1>
</div>
<div class="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <h2>underrubrik</h2>
</div>
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <div class="leftsidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Content text here</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
}
/* BANNER */
.topbanner {
    width: 980px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
/* HEADER */
.header {
    width: 980px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.header h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
.header h2 {
    margin: 0;
}
/* NAVIGATION LINKS */
.navigation {
    width: 980px;
    margin: auto;
}
.navigation a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
.navigation ul  {
    float: left;
    margin: -10px 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.navigation ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #fff;
}
.navigation ul li:first-child {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
.navigation ul li:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
/* CONTENT */
#main {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.leftsidebar {
    width: 20%;
    position: relative;
}
.leftsidebar ul {
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    list-style: none;
}
.leftsidebar ul li {
}
.content {      
}
.content p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing div tag?

Comment: Just for the record, the `z-index` property doesn't even apply to elements unless there is also a `position` property on that same element.

Comment: Also your `<h2>underrubrik<h2>` closing tag is another opening tag. Change to `<h2>underrubrik</h2>`

Comment: After editing and fixing the HTML markup here is what we can see: http://jsbin.com/bonide/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @JoelCox Thanks, I forgot closing tags on `<div>`and `<h2>underrubrik<h2>`. Always seem to forget those.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It doesn't look the same on my browser as it does in the output following your link. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the following for `.navigation ul` styles

```
margin: -10px 0 -10px 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
list-style: none;
```

Add `float: left;` to `.leftsidebar` to allow text to wrap around that, and add `padding-top: 20px 30px;` (adjust to your liking) to `.leftsidebar ul` to compensate for the overlap.

http://jsfiddle.net/ocfjsqpp/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting padding-left:0 in your ul container.

Answer (score 0):

Here have a look at what I did here with you code, also you haven't ended one of you h2 tags at the start.

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/4p6gdka9/ `enter code here`